# possible to pulse text by smoothly changing fontweight in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, text

I would like to add a fade in/out effect to some text (aka, a WPF Run object). I don't want it to toggle Bold/notBold all at once. I want it to animate between Bold and normal. Is this possible?

Comment: My guess is no, since you can only render text as bold or not, so the characters would jump around between the two.  If it is really important you could try writing your own text rendering algorithms, but I do not recommend it.  A better option would be to change the font color as you could easily transition between the two smoothly.  You could also use two labels, one bold and the other normal, then move the text from one to the other (character by character) creating a smoother transition.

Comment: I tried animating weight but got an error

Comment: I ended up pulsating the background color instead of the text. Thanks for the color suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can animate between Fontweights, as those are like fixed values that don't have "intermediate" states. I think the best bet is having 2 Textblocks (a Normal one and a Bold one with the same Text) and then animating Opacity of both, making the normal one fade out and the Bold one fade in. This way it will seem like the font is "transitioning" from normal to bold in an animated fashion.

```
<Control>
            <Control.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="btn" Content="IsBold"/>
                        <Grid Width="200">
                            <TextBlock Text="Transition" x:Name="normal" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Transition" FontWeight="Bold" Opacity="0" x:Name="bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" SourceName="btn" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard Duration="00:00:01">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="normal" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bold" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard Duration="00:00:01">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="normal" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bold" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>



                </ControlTemplate>
            </Control.Template>
        </Control>
```

Comment: Problem there is spacing.  When it is bold it is wider so the new text does on come in over tho old.  Still +1